# Check if multiple checkbox id's match multiple span text

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, label

I am using a set of checkboxes with labels to control what li's are visible in a ul, and am trying to target each li's span class to select them. However, instead of iterating over each checkbox, it is instead applying the code on the first checked element.

My code: (assumed there's a form tag surrounding these inputs)

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="1"><label for="1"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="2"><label for="2"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="3"><label for="3"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="4"><label for="4"></label>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">


<ul class="list-unstyled">
   <li><span class="platform">1</span></li>
   <li><span class="platform">2</span></li>
   <li><span class="platform">3</span></li>
   <li><span class="platform">4</span></li>
</ul>

$('form').submit(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.list-unstyled').each(function(){
        $(this).find('li').each(function(){
            if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('id') != $(this).find('.platform').text()){
                $(this).hide(200);
            }   
        });
    });

 });
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cj3q47vc/2/). What I would like is that if I have multiple checkboxes selected, then only those with the same span text are shown after hitting submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it was only working for the first `input` element was because you were only comparing the first `input` element's `id`:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').attr('id') // This will only select the first one
```

You should select the checkboxes by their `id` attributes based on the text of the current `.platform` element's text.

The condition could therefore be:

```
!$('input[type="checkbox"][id="' + $(this).find('.platform').text() + '"]:checked').length
```

Or shorter:

```
!$('[id="' + $('.platform', this).text() + '"]:checkbox:checked').length
```

The first portion is [an attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) which will select an element with the same `id` attribute as the current `.platform` element's text. The `:checkbox:checked` porition will limit the selection to only checked checkboxes, and then finally, `.length` is used to check if there are any matches, and `!` negates the results.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/04575as7/)

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.list-unstyled').each(function(){
        $(this).find('li').each(function(){
            if (!$('input[type="checkbox"][id="' + $(this).find('.platform').text() + '"]:checked').length){
                $(this).hide(200);
            } else {
                $(this).show(200);
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

You could shorten the snippet a little too:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/coxcfxko/)

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.list-unstyled li').each(function () {
        $(this).toggle(!$('[id="' + $('.platform', this).text() + '"]:checkbox:checked').length);
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Though I do not understand why. Could you please explain what the code is doing? (namely the "!" before $('input[type="checkbox"][id="' + $(this).find('.platform').text() + '"]:checked') as well as adding ".length()" at the end of it).

Comment: @user3183717 I added a little bit of an explanation :)